# Where to permanently set npm proxy?

Tags: macos, terminal, npm

To set a proxy when using npm I use :

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy.pro.com:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.pro.com:8080
```

I set this with each use of npm in mac terminal. Where should this command be added in order to permanently set the proxy so is available to all instances of terminal ?

I could run a startup script on mac boot but how to ensure the proxy config is available to all instances of terminal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put it in your `bash` profile, or other shell startup script. So, for example `$HOME/.profile`.

If you mean, *"all instances of Terminal for all users"*, then you would need to put it in `/etc/bashrc`.

Answer (score 6):

You can create a .npmrc file and place the config in there

```
proxy http://proxy.pro.com:8080
https-proxy http://proxy.pro.com:8080
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! FWIW, default `npmrc` location in Windows: `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc`. To check if its applied: `npm config edit`.

Answer (score 2):

```
npm config set https-proxy https://username:pwd@proxy.company.com:8080

npm config set proxy https://username:pwd@proxy.company.com:8080

npm config set sslVerify false

npm config set strict-ssl false

set HTTP_PROXY=http://username:pwd@proxy.company.com:8080

set HTTPS_PROXY=https://username:pwd@proxy.company.com:8080
```

**Permanently set proxy:**

Add `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` to System environment variables